# limit of 'exponential type' sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to study limits of the form $$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{p(i)}{i!}$$ where $p$ is a polynomial function of degree $d$.

For example, 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^2}{(i+1)!} = e-1$$
I want to study the limit for different polynomials. Currently, I am evaluating these limits by hand, by reducing them to partial fractions of factorials.

Is there any 'ready-made' formula, or any other approach that will be suitable for coding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start with the case where $p(i)$ is a monomial of the form $i^n$ and get the general results via linearity. In the monomial case the series is $$\sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{i^n}{i!} $$ In order to evalute this sum consider the function $$f_n(x)= \sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{x^i}{i!}=e^x-1. $$
If we differentiate both sides WRT $x$ we obtain
$$e^x=\sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{i x^{i-1}}{i!} $$
Next, multiply both sides by $x$ to find
$$x e^x=\sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{i x^{i}}{i!} $$
Plugging in $x=1$ we find the first sum: $\sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{i}{i!}=e$.

In order to find the sum with higher powers, consider the differential operator $\Theta=x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}$ (differentiation followed by multiplication by $x$). It follows that $$\sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{i^n}{i!}=\Theta^n \left[e^x-1 \right] \bigg|_{x=1}. $$ (Here $\Theta^n$ represents applying the operator $\Theta$ $n$ consecutive times.)

Comment: +1, I was just typing up the same thing.  You're fast!  To add a little more, it can be shown by induction that $$\Theta^n \left[e^x-1 \right] = e^z \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left\{\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right\} z^k,$$ where $\left\{\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right\}$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thank you!